# Get information of element that called function with jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, tags

I was wondering how I'd go about finding with jQuery, the element id that called an onClick method? my code is:

#### JS

```
function getInfo(event)
{
    console.log(event.target.id + " ... ");
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="menu-content" id="thisismyid">
    This is some placeholder text.<br>
    <a onClick="getInfo()" id="thisisthelinksid">Click on me</a>
</div>

<div class="menu-content" id="thisismysecondid">
    This is some more placeholder text.<br>
    <a onClick="getInfo()" id="thisistheotherlinksid">Click on me</a>
</div>
```

I can't put anything inside the parentheses of the function, because I want a function passed to it later, I just want to be able to tell which called this function.

I know this has been asked many times, and a lot of the questions have answers, but I have read through a lot of them and none have helped me.

Thanks guys

#### -EDIT-

In regards to the answers below at time of this edit, I cannot use the jQuery method like:

```
$("div.menu-content a").click(function() {
    some content here..
});
```

because I need it to only be run on certain links being clicked, not all of them. Does that help clarify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$("div.menu-content a").click(function() {
    var $elemId = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log($elemId + " .... ");
);
```

Is a much more "jQuery style" solution to do it.

Comment: Thanks, and I would have used that, except my code is going to be used for like an accordian style div being shown. However, I don't want it run on all the `<a>` tags, just select ones, hence the onClick method. Any solutions?

Comment: Look at $("div.menu-content a"), it's a selector (http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) which select only links on div with menu-content class. And we apply a click listener on him. I would recommend you to read a few jquery tutorial ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
function getInfo(event)
{
    var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work.  Unless the `onclick` attribute is `getInfo(event)` (which the OP says he can't change it to), then `event` will be undefined here, like it is in his code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use the `onclick` attributes, use event handlers instead.

```
$(function(){
   $('a', 'div.menu-content').click(function(){
      console.log(this.id+'...');
   });
}):
```